# Create/Initialize new object using variables

Tags: c++, object, initialization

I am intending to initialize or create a new object using variables.
The error says that i am conflicting declaration.

```
       //instantiate new node object***********************
        string peer = "peer";
        string pNo = convertInt(addPeerNum); //convert peer number to string to concatenate 2 strings
        string NewPeerObject = peer+pNo; << ERROR POINTS TO HERE
        nodes NewPeerObject; << ERROR POINTS TO HERE
```

Error message:

> conflicting declaration 'nodes NewPeerObject' <-- last line of error
>       'NewPeerObject' has a previous declaration as 'string NewPeerObject' <-- 2nd last line

My main point is to create a new object when I add more peers.
If I addpeer 1, it will create a new object 'peer1'
If I addpeer 2, it will be 'peer2' etc.

I am reading in the file which contains

```
 addpeer 1
 addpeer 100
 addpeer 28
```

In my program, it reads the file and stores the number in a variable called 'addPeerNum'
and with me doing this, it actually has a different string content of 'NewPeerObject'.

So in this instance, i am actually trying to create 3 new objects.

Is there any way which i will be able to do it?

Comment: Are you trying to create variables with dynamic names? If so, this is not possible, a variable is given a static name that is only use during compilation. Perhaps what you need is an associative container (a `map`, for instance) to associate a name with an object? Something like `std::map<std::string, Node>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that what you are looking for is a kind of dynamically resized array of your objects.
You can use `std::list` to achieve that kind of behavior.

```
std::list<PeerObject> list;
PeerObject peer(peer_string);
list.insert(peer);
```

or a `std::map` if you want to use your peer string as a key

```
std::map<std::string, PeerObject> peer_map;
PeerObject peer(peer_string);
peer_map.insert(peer_string, peer);
//    .... add more
PeerObject& foundObj = peer_map[a_key];
foundObj.doSomething();
```

You could also do it with MACROs but only at compile time and you should avoid them if possible.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot have two objects with same name like that. It violates the **[One definition Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule)**, naturally the compiler complains.
Just please do yourself a favor and change the name of either of them.

Comment: i am intending to create a new object automatically whenever i add a peer. so actually to simply say, 'NewObjectPeer' actually changes everytime when i add a new peer. it is a string and 'addPeerNum' changes everytime.

Comment: @Andres With Als on this one. This makes no sense.

Comment: @Andres: What your object contains is a different story, the problem is how your objects are *named* here.You cannot have same names for those objects.

Comment: @Als, My variable 'pNo' will be unique and will be always changing. Therefore the final combined string of my variable 'NewPeerObject' is always different in the end

Comment: @Andres: Are you trying to create variable name at run-time? You cannot do that.